# QFrame is not taking QWidget as parent?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget, qframe

what i am trying in here is Make CancelCross child of Notifier class but when i do that the cross of CancelCross is not visible. But if i unparent it then it visible fine. I tried parenting it with QMainWindow as well but no luck. Is there something wrong in my code ?

```
class CloseCrosss(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, QWidgetparent = None):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self, parent=QWidgetparent)


    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        pen = QtGui.QPen(Qt.red)
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(460, 10, 470, 20)
        qp.drawLine(470, 10, 460, 20)
        qp.end()


class Notifier(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, message=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        _desktop = QtGui.QApplication.desktop()
        size = _desktop.screenGeometry()

        self.resize(size.width() * 25 / 100, size.height() * 3 / 100)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.move(size.width() - (size.width() * 25 / 100) - 10, 50)

        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(message)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: lightgreen; font: 14px;")
        self.label.setIndent(20)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        s = self.size()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 200))
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 200))
        qp.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, s.width(), s.height(), 5, 5)
        qp.end()


    def closeEvent(self):
        self.kill()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    QApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Notifier()
    cross = CloseCrosss(QWidgetparent=window)
    window.show()
    cross.show()
    QApp.exec_()
```

Comment: why `10+450, 10, 20+450, 20`?

Comment: @eyllanesc oh i was just playing with some values, once i got perfect values i would change it to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positions of the children are relative to their parent, if a widget does not have a father then its position is relative to the screen. And that coordinate system is used to paint, for example in your case `qp.drawLine(460, 10, 470, 20)` is indicating that you are going to paint the line that goes from `(460, 10)` to `(470, 20)` to the Notifier. The height of Notifier is 3% of the screen, and for my *3% of the screen* it is much less than *470*, so the painting is discarded.

In your case I understand that you want to draw a cross of 10x10, then just draw that cross and then move it to the upper left corner.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class CloseCrosss(QtGui.QFrame):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, side=10, parent=None):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self._side = side
        self.setFixedSize(side, side)
        if parent:
            parent.installEventFilter(self)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()
        QtGui.QFrame.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
        qp.drawLine(0, 0, self._side, self._side)
        qp.drawLine(self._side, 0, 0, self._side)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if watched == self.parentWidget() and self.parentWidget():
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize:
                self.adjustSize()
        return QtGui.QFrame.eventFilter(self, watched, event)

    def adjustSize(self):
        # move widget to topright
        self.move(self.parentWidget().width() -self.width()-5, 5)


class Notifier(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, message=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, flags=QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        _desktop = QtGui.QApplication.desktop()
        size = _desktop.screenGeometry().size()

        self.resize(size.width() * 25 / 100, size.height() * 3 / 100)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.move(size.width() - (size.width() * 25 / 100) - 10, 50)

        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(message)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: lightgreen; font: 14px;")
        self.label.setIndent(20)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        cross = CloseCrosss(parent=self)
        cross.clicked.connect(self.close)


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 200))
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 200))
        qp.drawRoundedRect(QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), self.size()), 5, 5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    QApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Notifier("Hello World")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(QApp.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: thanks i understood the problem now. your answer is also correct but i found a shortcut. So I just added

``
`if QWidgetparent:
    size = self.parent().size()
    self.resize(size)`

Comment: @laslavinco If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: @laslavinco your solution is the same as mine but it has a disadvantage if you change the size of your window it will generate a problem, instead my solution will automatically be corrected.

Comment: yeah true i completely forgot that. Thanks for the help :)